# AVCaptureDevice isTorchActive always return NO

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avcapturedevice

Following code doesn't work correctly:

```
AVCaptureDevice *flashLight = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ([flashLight isTorchAvailable] && [flashLight isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn])
    {
        BOOL success = [flashLight lockForConfiguration:nil];
        if (success)
        {
            if ([flashLight isTorchActive])
            {
                //TURN OFF
                [flashLight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
            }
            else
            {
                //TURN ON
                [flashLight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
            }
            [flashLight unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
```

`[flashLight isTorchActive]` returns NO even if it's active.

**UPD:** Replacing ([flashLigh isTorchActive]) with if (flashLight.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchModeOn) helped. But if torch was previously activated from Control Center, i get AVCaptureTorchModeOff, when running this code first time.

Comment: Replace if ([flashLigh isTorchActive]) with if (flashLight.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchModeOn)